# Create .tar.gz archive on Windows 10 using Python 3.6 and tarfile module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, tar

I am attempting to create a tar.gz archive file in a Windows 10 folder. Idea is that in my folder I start with my input file and finish with my input file and a .tar.gz archive of the same name.

Problem is it that my code seems to be applying some sort of compression to the original file and not creating a new file with a .tar.gz file type.

Code is below. Can anyone assist?

```
import os
import tarfile

full_path = 'C:\\Myfolder\\MyArchive.txt'
my_root = 'C:\\MyFolder\\'

tar = tarfile.open(full_path, "w:gz")
tar.add(my_root)
tar.close()
```

Comment: Erm, you are requesting a `.tar.gz` file, which means a tarball with gzip compression. If you want a plain, uncompressed tarball, don't add `:gz` there.

Comment: no i do want it compressed...however i start with 'MyArchive.txt' and I am expecting to end up with 'MyArchive.txt' and 'MyArchive.tar.gz'...however the compression appears to be being applied to the original file instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create a .tar.gz file with a single file in the same directory as the original file, only suffixed with `.tar.gz`. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

```py
import tarfile

original_path = "C:\\Myfolder\\MyArchive.txt"
tgz_path = original_path + ".tar.gz"

with tarfile.open(tgz_path, "w:gz") as tar:
   tar.add(original_path)
```